# How can I recognize and distinguish musical instruments by timbre? (without machine learning)

Tags: python, music

I understand that there is a the Timbre but I don't really understand how can I use it to differ them from each other and actually don't understand what is a Timbre, is it a graph? Is it a number that I can calculate? How do I describe it? Because I need to write a python code that recognizes which instrument is played and I am kind of stuck.. thanks !

Comment: Is it a busy mix of polyphonic instruments? Or a clean, monophonic transcribed recording?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is to use [timbral_models](https://github.com/AudioCommons/timbral_models) to extract timbral characteristics.

> The current distribution contains python scripts for ... eight timbral characteristics: hardness, depth, brightness, roughness, warmth, sharpness, booming, and reverberation.

Comment: geez, instead of just GitHub, i wish there was a paper with math describing all 8 timbre measures.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I am not an expert on the subject so maybe I am unable to judge quality of any paper. A good starting point is to check the [audio commons materials](https://www.audiocommons.org/materials/), e.g. [D5.1](https://www.audiocommons.org/assets/files/AC-WP5-Surrey-D5.1%20Hierarchical%20ontology%20of%20timbral%20semantic%20descriptors.pdf). Or for a reference from the academic literature, the open access paper [Timbral attributes for sound effect library searching](https://www.aes.org/tmpFiles/elib/20220203/18754.pdf) from 2017.

Also, the question explicitly tags python.